# How to define alias for gdb function

Tags: gdb

**GDB** supports function by command `define`. I want to write a helper script for GDB, and I hope each function has a meaningful name and an alias, just like `bt` and `backtrace`.

Does GDB support this feature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(gdb) apropos alias
alias -- Alias one command to another
aliases -- Aliases of other commands
```

Answer (score 4):

An example to complete matt's answer:

```
alias ir = info registers
ir
```

as documented at: https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Aliases.html

Unlike Bash aliases, you *cannot* pass arguments to the definition of those aliases, e.g.:

```
alias ir = info registers eax
```

The `registers` part is only accepted because it is not an argument, but a subcommand.

But you can pass arguments when using the alias:

```
ir eax
```

You can then list all currently defined aliases with:

```
help aliases
```